# How do I enable bank transfer payment in backend only

Tags: payment

Is it possible to make a bank transfer payment method available only for manual order at the back-end?

Comment: Is it recommend to edit core files, how did you achieved in a safe way? @snh_nl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to override the `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Banktransfer` model using a typical rewrite, and you'll want to set both `_canUseCheckout` & `_canUseMultishipping` properties to `false`; ref. the properties in [`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php#L50):

```
/**
 * Payment Method features
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isGateway                   = false;
protected $_canOrder                    = false;
protected $_canAuthorize                = false;
protected $_canCapture                  = false;
protected $_canCapturePartial           = false;
protected $_canRefund                   = false;
protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial     = false;
protected $_canVoid                     = false;
protected $_canUseInternal              = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout              = true;
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = true;
protected $_isInitializeNeeded          = false;
protected $_canFetchTransactionInfo     = false;
protected $_canReviewPayment            = false;
protected $_canCreateBillingAgreement   = false;
protected $_canManageRecurringProfiles  = true;
```

Comment: Thanks - looks good. his way I first enable it in backend, and then set these two variables to allow it to be seen in backend only. Is there a way to set these vaiables dynamicallu (during onestepcheckout? then I dont need to override the whole method)

Comment: These could only be set via Reflection.

Comment: @snh_nl you can do it by dynamically create store config and access it in banktransfer model