# Enable Credit Card Save just for backend orders

Tags: orders, payment, backend, payment-gateway

I have a credit card gateway with my bank but does not allow backend orders... Is there a way where I can place backend orders for some clients that prefer placing orders over the phone and use the CC save payment method? I will manually check the cards and put them trough a manual credit card machine.
Love to hear some expert opinion on this :)

Looking forward to your replies!

Cheers

Comment: Be more specific. What payment module are using? Some of them just implement frontend order placing. If this is the case there is not much todo other than implement it yourself.

Comment: Also see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-do-i-enable-bank-transfer-payment-in-backend-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each payment method that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` has the following member variables:

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; //can use in admin
protected $_canUseCheckout              = true; //can use in onepage checkout
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = true; //can use in multishipping
```

As shown above they are default 'true'.

If you want to use a method only for admin override their values in your payment model as follows:

```
protected $_canUseInternal              = true; //can use in admin
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; //can use in onepage checkout
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false; //can use in multishipping
```

Then enable the method from the **system->configuration->payment methods** section.
It shouldn't appear in the frontend (but test it in case I'm wrong) but you should be able to see it in when creating an order from the backend.

Comment: It is true that these variables control where the payment methods are displayed, but some of them being false usually means that there is no implementation for the admin backend.

Comment: Thanks Marius! Seems not to hard to dig into... I always had fear of touching things in Magento but this one does not seem to hard.